# Display button when hover over certain row in table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, html

I am trying to make a button show up when I mouseover a certain row. The $index variable is the total number of rows in the table. The "#r"+a.toString() variable refers to the id of the table row and "#b"+a.toString() refers to the button of the row that I want to be displayed when I hover over a certain row of the table. Currently it displays the button in the last row whenever I mouseover any row.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        for(a=1; a <= <?php echo $index; ?>; a++){
        var button = $("#b"+a.toString());
        $("#r"+a.toString()+" td").mouseover(function(){
            button.css({"visibility": "visible"});
        });
        $("tr td").mouseout(function(){
            button.css({"visibility": "hidden"});
        });
    }
    });
</script>



<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr> 
                            <th>Item</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php 
                        $item_array;
                        $index = 0;
                        $index_2 = 1;
                        $r = "r";
                        $b="b";
                        foreach ($item_array as $id_array){ ?>

                            <tr id="<?php echo $r.$index_2; ?>">
                             <td><?php echo $item_array[$index] ?></td>
                                <td> <?php echo $quantity_array[$index] ?></td>
               <td>   
                        <form method='POST' action='edit.php'>
                            <?php echo $price_array[$index];?>
                            <button id="<?php echo $b.$index_2; ?>" type="button" style="float:right; visibility:hidden; align-content:right;" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Edit</button>
                        </form>
                    </td><?php
                        $index++;
                        $index_2++;

                        echo "</tr>";
                        } ?>

                </table>
```

Comment: Can you share the html code associated with this?

Comment: So what is happening or not happening? Is the button becoming visible but not becoming hidden on mouseout? Not becoming visible at all? etc.

Comment: I just editted my post and currently: it displays the button in the last row whenever I mouseover any row

Comment: Do I need the for loop?

Comment: How do I use the edit button to edit that specific row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ID's is making this  more complicated than needed when a simple traverse will suffice.

```
$(function(){
    $('tr').hover(function(){ /* hover first argument is mouseenter*/
        $(this).find('button').css({"visibility": "visible"});
    },function(){  /* hover second argument is mouseleave*/
       $(this).find('button').css({"visibility": "hidden"});
    });

});
```

For more granularity give the buttons a common class.

Even simpler is using CSS alone

```css
button.buttonCLass{ visibility: hidden;}
tr:hover button.buttonCLass{ visibility: visible;}
```

Comment: Your code is nice....I'm upvoting it as a good solution....semi-colons in css at bottom of post?

Comment: I'm tried the css version and don't know why it isn't working

Comment: do I need to set each tr:hover to a specific id for each tr? Hopefully that makes sense...

Comment: @user3479298....did you try the jQuery written by charlietfl? As an outsider, I believe that code block "should" work (so should my code :)  ) so if these answers aren't working there is probably some subtle issue in your code that we are missing...check your php error log and your DOM to make sure there is not something else going on (e.g., PHP Notice: Undefined Variable, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your "button" variable gets reset every time the loop runs.  By the time the loop is done running, "button" remains as the last value it ever had.  That's why the button in the last row is the one that is always showing up whenever you have over something.  Instead, you need to find the button from within the event handlers.  Also, you can have a single event handler on the table ("delegate") to handle ALL row hovers. Then if you dynamically add/remove table rows you don't have to worry about binding and unbinding events.

```
$('table').on('mouseover', 'tr', function(ev) {
    $(this).find('button').css({'visibility': 'visible'});
}).on('mouseout', 'tr', function(ev) {
    $(this).find('button').css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is true...OP does want that variable to be reset with each iteration to align a button id with a table row id

Comment: be careful using `target`, could be a span inside a td for example in which case `find` will fail. `this` will definitely be the `tr` though

Comment: @charlietfl - thanks.  Wrote it really quickly.  `this` should refer to the table row. @ChemistryBlob - I know that while the iteration is happening he wants button updated.  But by the time the hover happens, button still refers to the last one unless you put it inside of some sort of closure.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite this code:

```
$("#r"+a.toString()+" td").mouseover(function(){
    button.css({"visibility": "visible"});
});
$("tr td").mouseout(function(){
    button.css({"visibility": "hidden"});
});
```

as

```
$("#r"+a.toString()+" td").mouseover(function () {
    button.css({"visibility": "visible"});
}).mouseout(function () {
    button.css({"visibility": "hidden"});
});
```

It seems to me that you bind the mouseout event to the mousing out from any cell of any table in your document. In the code block I wrote, you bind the mouseout to only your specific table cell that has that specific button.

Also, be certain that in `<?php echo $index; ?>`, $index is of type int, else your for loop will not work.

Comment: It's still doing the same thing, the last row is showing the button whenever I hover over any row.

Comment: Are you sure $index is an int?